# Unicode Composition in Sublime Text

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, sublime-text-2, ubuntu-unity

I'm not able to use unicode composition (The <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> method) to enter unicode characters in Sublime Text 2 (v2.0.1, Build 2217) on Ubuntu 12.04 (Unity).  To reproduce, just open up a tab and do this:

1. Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>
2. Type  `00B0`
3. Press <kbd>enter</kbd>

Normally the degree sign (°) will be entered. I'm not sure if some Sublime command is overriding this keybinding, Is anyone else able to do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I just ran into this same issue and I couldn't find an answer anywhere, but I did find a solution. The problem is that the default key bindings in Sublime for Linux overwrite `ctrl+shift+u` with a `soft_redo` command. To disable this:

1. Open up your default key bindings: `Preferences > Key Bindings - Default`
2. Search for `ctrl+shift+u` and comment out the line containing that key binding. For example: `//{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+u"], "command": "soft_redo" },`. Optionally, you could remap this to a different key binding if you *really* want `soft_redo` (<s>I have no idea what this command does</s> See comment below for `soft_redo` functionality).
3. Save and you're good to go!

One note though, you'll need to use `<space>` instead of `<enter>` when you've completed the unicode character code as Sublime has a key binding for `<enter>`.

#### Edit:

Since you can no longer easily edit the default key bindings in Sublime Text 3, I would suggest using the [answer](https://superuser.com/a/671651/187006) by @brandon-lockaby.

Comment: Thanks, Michael. This solution fixes the problem easily!

Comment: btw, any idea on soft redo? what is it?

Comment: You need to restart sublime.

Comment: You don't have to restart sublime. Any time you save a sublime configuration file, sublime reloads the configuration. As for the `soft_undo` and `soft_redo` they are used to undo/redo selections when you are making multiple selections. For instance, if you mistakenly added a selection to your multi-selection, you can perform a `soft_undo` to undo the last selection without losing all your other selections.

Answer (score 24):

I also got here, but these days it seems you really aren't meant to edit the default settings, and the binding can't be unbound in user settings.

My solution is to press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> in sublime.  It works and I don't have to change any key bindings.  Still have to press space when you're done.

Comment: `Ctrl + Alt + Shift + U` does not work for me with Sublime Text 3 on Debian 7.

Comment: `ctrl+alt+shift+u` does not work in Sublime Text  3 on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Works on my machine, Ubuntu 16.04 Sublime 3. I also use Character Table package because it offers a search functionality and additional keybindings that are easier to memorise

Comment: Does not work for me, Ubuntu 16.04, Sublime 3.  CTRL-Shift-u works fine from Terminator, Firefox, etc.

Comment: Works for me now on 20.04, thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Being a Vim user, I'm used to working with my keyboard, and while my IDE is heavily configured, I like to use default options for computers which are not mine, for instance. This should work.

#### A possible solution which should work on any default setup:

Type any letter or word (just a placeholder), and just hit `Ctrl+D`. It selects the word.

Then press `Ctrl+H`. It opens search and replace. Hit `Tab`, type `\x{<unicode>}`, making sure RegEx is activated (toggled with `Alt+R`), and hit `Ctrl+Shift+H` to replace it with the Unicode value.

Hit `Esc` to close the search and replace menu.

#### If you need the same Unicode several times

After you've done one replacement, you can repeat the same process by selecting (with `Ctrl+D` again) whatever you want, and `Ctrl+Shift+H` will automatically replace it, since it stores your last replacement in memory. No need to bring up the menu again.

## TL;DR:

Use search and replace. `\x{<unicode}` in RegEx mode will serve as Unicode characters.

Answer (score 1):

By Editing 'Default (Linux).keymap' in /opt/sublime_text/Packages/Default.sublime-package one could disable the conflicting ctrl+shift+u binding

Answer (score 0):

In Sublime Text 3 you cannot alter the Default key bindings...normally. However, if you install [PackageResourceViewer](https://github.com/skuroda/PackageResourceViewer), you can use the command `PackageResourceViewer: Open Resource` and then choose `Default`, then `Default (Linux).sublime.keymap`...and then you can delete (or comment out) the `soft_redo` line, and save the file.

Answer (score 0):

The above solutions did not work for me on Ubuntu 22.04, using Sublime Build 4143.

The only solution that worked was to repeat the keybinding in the user keybinding, ommiting the "command":

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+u"] }
```

It won't show the underline "u" like other editors do, though. It will still print the correct character after entering the number and hitting the space key.